# How many subsets are possible

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am completely confused how to solve it

How many ordered or unordered pair of subset of a given set $A$ are possible. if  $n(A)=x$

Comment: If I understand your question, you're asking how many $B_1$ and $B_2$'s there are such that $B_1,B_2\subseteq A$ and $B_1\cap B_2=\emptyset$ (with or without order).  Is this correct?

Comment: What does $n(A)=x$ even mean?

Comment: Is $A $ assumed finite?

Comment: $A$ is finite  $n(A)$ means cardinality

Answer (score 1):

There are $2^{n(A)}$ many subsets of $A$. This means there are

$$(2^{n(A)})^2=2^{2n(A)}$$

ordered pairs and

$${2^{n(A)}\choose 2}=\frac12(2^{n(A)}(2^{n(A)}-1))=2^{n(A)-1}(2^{n(A)}-1)$$

unordered pairs.